# How to enable markdown-mode every time I invoke Emacs Anywhere?

Tags: hooks, frames, markdown, server

I am using a cool software called [Emacs
Anywhere](https://github.com/zachcurry/emacs-anywhere).

Usually, I invoke this software to write on Stack Overflow and on
GitHub. Both websites use markdown.

Hence, almost every time I invoke Emacs Anywhere, I need to manually
enable markdown mode.

I have markdown-mode with this package installed in my init file:

```lisp
;; This package brings keybindings similar to org-mode, but to
;; markdown format!
(use-package markdown-mode
  :ensure t
  :mode ("README\\.md\\'" . gfm-mode)
  :init (setq markdown-command "multimarkdown"))
```

I would like to make things more automatic. Take into account that for
Emacs Anywhere to work it is necessary to have an **Emacs server** going on.
This is provided by my config file, with:

```lisp
;; Start server so that I can easily launch succesfully the
;; application called Emacs Anywhere
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'server-start)
```

Also, every time Emacs Anywhere is invoked, Emacs creates *a new
frame*. Moreover, there is an addition of a new buffer called **Emacs Anywhere**.

Finally, what triggers the invocation of Emacs Anywhere is **not** exactly
Emacs, but a shortcut defined on System Preference of the macOS.

Hence, I would like to ask, what is the best approach to **automate
the process of enabling** `markdown-mode`? How to do it?

1 - Creating a hook *enabling markdown* triggered by frame
creation *in general*?

Obs.: Maybe I am missing something, but I believe I only use Emacs new
frames after invoking Emacs anywhere. It does not seem to be useful in
my day-to-day activies programming, on Magit, dired, org-mode files...

2 - Creating a hook based on some inner workings of the Emacs server? For instance, a hook catching the connection between Emacs Anywhere and the frame creation?

3 - Maybe a hook triggered by the creation of buffer name written as `*Emacs Anywhere*`?

4 - Another approach?

Comment: `markdown-mode` doesn't seem to be included in vanilla Emacs. Please add some info about it to your question. It's impossible to know from your question what it is or does - minor mode? global/local? major mode?

Comment: Thank you trying to help, @Drew. Indeed the question was missing information. I have just updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspection of the github page you linked to shows that Emacs Anywhere already provides hooks for this purpose and examples of their use.  Look here: https://github.com/zachcurry/emacs-anywhere#hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @FranBurstall, I looked at the documentation, and then I wrote the following:

```lisp
;; Define a function to enable markdown-mode after Emacs Anywhere is invoked
(defun pmd/markdown-mode-emacs-anywhere (app-name window-title x y w h)
  (markdown-mode))

;; Hook your function
(add-hook 'ea-popup-hook 'pmd/markdown-mode-emacs-anywhere)
```

Not sure if this is the most elegant way to do it... But it works! :)

I tried removing all parameters. But it broke the function. So I am leaving it with all this *unused* parameters.

Comment: It sounds like you should accept Fran's answer as that did in fact solve your problem.

Comment: ok, I forgot to do it. Thanks